# Can't bind socket with external IP, only localhost works

Tags: python, sockets, bind

This is my code:

```
HOST = 'localhost'
PORT = 1979

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
print 'Socket created!'

try:
    s.bind((HOST, PORT))
except socket.error as msg:
    print 'Failed'
    sys.exit()

print 'Socket bind complete'

s.listen(20)

print 'Listening...'                         ...
```

Everything works fine with localhost. But when I enter my external IP as HOST it fails at s.bind and gives me the error "Failed". (the port is opened).
What is the reason for that and how can I fix that?

edit: After changing the code I can see the error: [Errno 99] Cannot assign requested adress

Comment: Please add the full error track back!

Comment: 1979, this port probably is already opened in your server, and it couldn't bind your socket into it. check with `netstat -ntlp` if this port is already there.

Comment: Hello, I got the normal error track: [Errno 99] Cannot assign requested adress

Comment: Which IP address are you trying to bind? My guess it that you are in local netwok with a NAT between you and the external network and the IP address you try to bind is not  an IP address of one of the interfaces of your PC.

Comment: I'm using a VPN for this. The IP I entered was the Ip of the vpn server I'm connected to. Is that the problem? If yes, how can I fix this?

Comment: You can only bind IP addresses that correspond to the ones assigned to your interfaces. This is why your script fails.

Comment: @abc Thanks for your help ! Do you also know how I can fix that on linux? Or is there even a way to fix that?

Comment: There is nothing to "fix". A given program can only use the local IP addresses. You need to explain more the core problem you have and you try to address.

Comment: I just got it working with replacing the IP in my script with "0.0.0.0". Thank you all for your help !